# Tensorflow adam optimizer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a net in Tensorflow and I am trying to reimplement it in Keras. Currently compared to the Tensorflow model the Keras model completly underperforms. The loss is much higher and decreases slower compared to the original model. My best guess is that I am using the wrong Optimizer. In the Tensorflow code the Optimizer looks like this:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.0001,
                                           global_step,
                                           decay_steps=10000,
                                           decay_rate=0.33,   
                                           staircase=True)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, epsilon=1e-8)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step)
```

In Keras it looks like this:

```
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
model.compile(loss=get_loss_funcs(), optimizer=adam)
```

Is there a way to implement the Tensorflow optimizer in Keras?

Comment: Normally, you should not need to add exponential decay to Adam, since it is already there; nevertheless, you seem not to be the only one trying this (and reporting better results) - this might be of help (arguably, the solution would indeed be to decay the `lr` through a callback): [Learning rate decay in addition to Adam?](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/9)

Comment: @desertnaut this seems to be the solution. My loss is still very bad, but i guess the problem is in some other part of my code. If you formulate this as an answer I will accept it. Thank you very much

Comment: What about `TFOptimizer` answer below? Did you try it?

Comment: I realized the optimizer is not the problem, because the training performs way worse even in the first 10000 iterations. So before the exponential_decay of the learning_rate comes into effect

Comment: Fair; I gave @Alexis an upvote though, since I didn't know that detail...

Comment: not needed :) i've answered the last question but haven't solve the issue...

Answer (score 5):

yes there is! - [TFOptimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/#tfoptimizer)

```
class TFOptimizer(Optimizer):
"""Wrapper class for native TensorFlow optimizers.
"""
```

it's called like this:

```
keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(optimizer)
```

the wrapp will help you see if the issue is due to the optimiser.

Comment: Does the keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(optimizer) account for the global step?

Comment: But only in optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step) we say that the global_step should be increased every iteration. With keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(optimizer) we would not give Keras this information, so Keras would need to assume that it has to increase the global_step every iteration. I am not sure whether Keras does this

Comment: So like this? `optimizerTF = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, epsilon=1e-8)`, then `kOpt=keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(optimizerTF)`, then `model.compile(loss=get_loss_funcs(), optimizer=kOpt)` ?